# Python- writing sensor data to a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code where I can take in data from an analog sensor and want to write the data to a .txt file. I did some research and wrote this code-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
datafile = file.open("temperature.txt", "w")

def ReadChannel(channel):
    adc = spi.xfer2([1, 8+channel <<4, 0])
    data = ((adc[1]& 3) << 8) + adc[2]
    return data

def ConvertVolts(data, places):
    volts = (data*3.3)/float(1023)
    volts = round(volts, places)
    return volts

def ConvertTemp(data, places):
    temp = ((data*200)/float(1023))-50
    temp = round(temp, places)
    return temp

temp_channel = 0
delay = 5

while True:
    temp_level = ReadChannel(temp_channel)
    temp_volts = ConvertVolts(temp_level, 2)
    temp = ConvertTemp(temp_level, 2)

    print"Temperature (deg F): ", temp
    datafile.write(str(temp)+"\n")
    time.sleep(delay)

datafile.close()
```

But when I run this code, it forms a file "temperature.txt" with no text in it. Could anyone please point out my mistake? If it helps, I have taken some inspiration from the following websites-
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/temperature/step10.py
http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/10/analogue-sensors-on-the-raspberry-pi-using-an-mcp3008/
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it the same when you use `w` and `a` flags or is it just `w` that doesn't work? Additionally, do you have the rights to do file writing and things in that folder (windows/linux) ? Also, you don't need to do `file.open`, simply `open` will do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. I used the open command as you suggested. I also used     chmod u+rw filename.py 
But it still doesn't write anything in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your file output stream never gets flushed to disk, as you just write to the file but then end the loop with control-c, right?

Maybe try to let the loop run 10 times and close the file then, as a try.
Do you get the correct print Temperature outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the builting logging function?? Then it could look something like this!

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=PATHTOFILE, loglevel=logging.INFO)
```

then you could just:

```
logging.info("TEXTTOWRITETOTHEFILEHERE")
```

instead of datafile.write(......)
It will append to the file if exists and adding date/time to it. it will also handle the file eg. close() ect. 
Shouldnt be needing the delay!

Answer (score 0):

change line:

```
datafile = file.open("temperature.txt", "w")
```

to this:

```
datafile = open("temperature.txt", "w")
```

as it is working for me now. If still not writing to file, check obtaining of sensor data. If **temp** variable is printed properly, read following please.

For your purpose is better use the **with** keyword,
becouse it includes .close() and even try/finally block (very suitable in looping formula). You will probably want use "a" mode to add data, then "w" mode to rewrite them:

```
while True:
    #read temp here
    with open("temperature", "a") as datafile:
        datafile.write(temp)
```

instead of less consistent:

```
datafile = open("temperature.txt", "w")
while True:
    #temp here
    datafile.write(temp)
datafile.close()
```

which actually never closes the file...